# elasticsearch do not analyze field

Tags: elasticsearch, analyzer

I use Elasticsearch (2.4) and I have an index with a field that is, in theory, analyzed on index step. But, in practice, it's not analyzed. I think I miss something, but what ?

**The complete index definition :**

```
{
   "test_index": {
      "aliases": {},
      "mappings": {
         "users": {
            "properties": {
               "name": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "analyzer": "my_analyser"
               },
               "id": {
                  "type": "long"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "settings": {
         "index": {
            "index_directly": "1",
            "number_of_shards": "1",
            "cron_limit": "50",
            "creation_date": "1496150121337",
            "analysis": {
               "analyzer": {
                  "standard": {
                     "type": "standard",
                     "max_token_length": "255",
                     "stopwords": ""
                  },
                  "my_analyser": {
                     "type": "custom",
                     "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
                  }
               },
               "tokenizer": {
                  "my_tokenizer": {
                     "token_chars": [
                        "letter",
                        "digit"
                     ],
                     "min_gram": "3",
                     "type": "ngram",
                     "max_gram": "3"
                  }
               }
            },
            "fields": {
               "name": {
                  "type": "text"
               }
            },
            "number_of_replicas": "0",
            "uuid": "lmwPFWoISlC2knZZn2nNZQ",
            "version": {
               "created": "2040599"
            }
         }
      },
      "warmers": {}
   }
}
```

**A simple document to index :**

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "John"
}
```

**The result :**

```
{
   "_index": "test_index",
   "_type": "users",
   "_id": "0",
   "_version": 1,
   "found": true,
   "_source": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "John"
   }
}
```

**What I am expecting :**

```
{
   "_index": "test_index",
   "_type": "users",
   "_id": "0",
   "_version": 1,
   "found": true,
   "_source": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": [
        "Joh",
        "ohn"
      ]
   }
}
```

I have other fields on this index, and I want my custom analyzer just on `name` field.

Comment: The analysis process will not modify the source document you're throwing into ES. The tokens `Joh` and `ohn` are in your index, but the source document will never contain them.

Comment: OK, thank you @Val
Is there a way to get the indexed value ? (without the Analyze API) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analyzer won't affect the `_source` object, it only impacts the result terms that are stored in index and used for search